# Error : 80004004, while updating any application, and also not able to uninstall the application

Tags: 8.0, whatsapp, app-update

Again an issue with my device, I got an update that you can update Whatsapp and one more application, but when I try to update the device it gives me the error: 80004004.

Comment: Are you able to access internet properly? Try reinstall app through live.com.

Comment: Yes, the internet browser is working fine. But I am not able to update the whatsapp.

Comment: Can you try a reinstall from [here](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/my/purchase-history‎)

Comment: OK thanks, but this time another error message: Not found
The page you want doesn't exist on this site.
8ddf25f8-c1a6-4273-891b-babaa2534708

Comment: You can see a menu below search box there. Open the menu then click on `Purchase History`.

Comment: Ohk Sure sir thanks, But I have one question, why exactly this issue is occering. Because of Whatsapp or device is having some issues.

Comment: Which phone you are using and do you faced same problems with apps other than Whatsapp? Did you tried soft or hard reset yet?

Comment: Soft reset I did, but the same issue is there, and the device is HTC Windows 8X.